# JavaFX 8 memory leak with Service class

Tags: java, memory, javafx, service, javafx-8

I have the following JavaFX 8 code.  It's purpose is to update, every 5 seconds, a StringProperty with a description of how much memory is being used.  I display the contents of the StringProperty in the UI.

```
    // Step 1 -- create a DoubleProperty for the used memory
    final DoubleProperty usedMemoryInMb = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    // Step 2 -- bind the text of the label to the property 
    final Label memoryUsedText = new Label ();
    final NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.0");
    memoryUsedText.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "Memory Used: " + f.format(usedMemoryInMb.get()) + " MB", usedMemoryInMb) );
    // Step 3 -- create a JavaFX 8 Service that will periodically calculate the used memory
    ScheduledService<Double> usedMemoryService = new ScheduledService<Double>() {

        protected Task<Double> createTask() {
            return new Task<Double>() {
                @Override
                protected Double call() throws Exception {
                    long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
                    long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                    double usedMemory = (double)(totalMemory - freeMemory) / (double)(1024 * 1024);
                    return usedMemory;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    // Step 4 -- tell the service to update our property whenever it runs.  We do not do this in the Task because this property is displayed and you can only update the display in the main JavaFX thread.
    usedMemoryService.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            usedMemoryInMb.set((Double) t.getSource().getValue());
        }
    });
    // Step 5 -- start the service to run every 5 seconds
    usedMemoryService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));
    usedMemoryService.setRestartOnFailure(true);
    usedMemoryService.start();
```

When I run the UI, I find that every 5 seconds, the reported memory usage increases by just over 3 Mb!  I don't have any other services running, but just to make sure that *this* service was to blame, I changed it to run every 1 second.  Sure enough, every 1 second, the memory usage increased by that same amount (just over 3Mb).

I have the '-verbose:gc' option turned on to verify there is no garbage collecting happening.  (That would decrease the memory anyway, not increase it).

I cannot see what I am doing in my `Service` that would even allocate 3Mb.  I imagine (not confirmed) that when GC does happen, most of this extra memory will be freed.  But still, it's troubling to see the memory increasing so quickly and it is sort of skewing the results of what I was trying to accomplish.

Can someone tell me what I am doing to use so much memory every time the `Service` runs?

Comment: It potentially creates new threads, or at least starts something running on an existing (but unused) thread. That's a pretty expensive operation. There's no evidence at all here of a "memory leak" though; as you say, once the GC runs all that should be freed up. Nothing in your `call()` method takes any appreciable time to run: why use all the overhead of a `Service` here? Why not just do this in a `Timeline`, which (I would expect) would be much more lightweight?

Comment: No reason except I viewed this as a "background" task and felt it "wrong" somehow to put this in the UI thread.  I may end up going that way.  FYI, I tried making the `Task` class into a `static` class and return a new instance of that.  It lowered the "leak" down to 2.2Mb per iteration.

Comment: So it's the anonymous inner class that is expensive. Interesting - I guess that makes some kind of sense.

Comment: I changed to use a `Timeline` as you suggested.  It's much better now.  Thanks for giving me the nudge!